# PWA push notifications. Message only appears in console.

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Finally I'm close to the finish line. I can send and receive push notifications via `Firebase`. But messages are only visible in console log (should be nice notification dialog).

Message in console log:

```
onMessage:  
{data: {…}, from: "493.......061", collapse_key: "do_not_collapse"}
collapse_key
:
"do_not_collapse"
data
:
{title: "My title", body: "Message Body here", status: "Message Body here"}
from
:
"493........061"
__proto__
:
Object
```

And i have two files with code:

```
sw.js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
  });
}

 var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB8H.....................Lxdrz480",
    authDomain: "project-name.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-name.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project-name",
    storageBucket: "project-name.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "49.........1061"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
      console.log('Have permission');
      return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token)
  {console.log(token); }
  )
.catch(function(err){
    console.log('Error Ocurred');
})


messaging.onMessage(
function(payload) {console.log('onMessage: ', payload);}

)
```

and

```
firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-messaging.js');

 var config = {
    apiKey: "...................",
    authDomain: "project-name.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-name.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project-name",
    storageBucket: "project-name.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "493..........1"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

For me looks like the file `firebase-messaging.js` never fires.

Comment: Have you defined  `gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"` at `manifest.json` file.

Comment: Yes. This line is in manifest

Comment: Actually, I think it is not the problem but you initialize double the firebase config. you initialize both sw.js and firebase-messaging-sw.js. This does not give any error on your console? you load first at sw.js but necessary script loading at the second  firebase-messaging-sw.js file.

Comment: No there is no errors. Only fcm token

Comment: You need to request permission to receive notifications from client. Assuming it is also done.

Comment: Yes this is working fine

Comment: If you like to check one more time with `messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {console.log(currentToken)...`  weather permission granted or !

Comment: No. All permissions is fine. I can see token in console log and i can receive messages in console log. But looks like `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is not working

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check the notification payload. It must be in the format:

```
{
   notification: 
   {
       title: 'Notifications are cool',
       body: 'Know how to send notifications',
       icon: 'https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256.png',
       vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
       data: 
       {
          url: 'https://images.com/image001.png' 
       }
   }
}
```

If you just send, for instance:

```
{
   title: 'Notifications are cool',
   body: 'Know how to send notifications'
}
```

the notification will appear in console, but not as a push notification.

Comment: Is it OK if the notifications don't appear with the payload structure you've shown, but **without a title**? When I send **title-only** notification or **title + body** one, they appear normally.